# seaching 2D ArrayLib does not work for some cases

Tags: actionscript, multidimensional-array

I have 2D array in which the second column has domain names of some emails, let us call the array myData[][].  I decided to use ArrayLib in order to search the second column for a specific domain.
ArrayLib.indexOf(myData, 1, domain)
Here is where I found an issue. In myData array, one of the domains look like this "ewmining.com" (pay attention to the w).
While searching for "e.mining.com" (notice the first dot), the indexOf() function actully gave me the row containing "ewmining.com".

This is what is in the array            "ewmining.com"
This is what is in the serach string    "e.mining.com"

It seams that ArrayLib treats the dot to mean any character.  Is this supposed to be the correct behavior?  Is there a way to stop this behavior and search for exact match.
I really need help on this issue.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The dot usually represents "any character" in regular expressions. I am not familiar with ArrayLib, but maybe you should look for a way to turn off regular expressions when searching. Otherwise you might have to escape the dot, for example search for e[.]mining[.]com

Comment: Did you try escaping with square brackets like I did?

Comment: firstly, do you know that its regex causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, I know that regex is causing the problem.  But I am not sure how to tell ArrayLib to do exact match not to use regular expression.  I tried escaping the dots in the domain.  I tried 2 cases. one like this e\.mining\.com and in the other trial I tried this e[.]mining[.]com.  Could someone please tell me what else I need to try.  I really appreciate any help.  Thanks

Comment: Can you add a link to the library you are using? Also, have you tried escaping the backslash (i.e. with a double backslash) 

e\\.mining\\.com